# Как сделать прозрачную "дырку"

Tags: html, css

Над элементом с контентом есть полупрозрачный элемент, в котором нужно сделать прозрачную круглую "дырку". Как это сделать с помощью стилей css?

Comment: Экстрасенсы в отпуске. Показывайте пример кода.

Comment: @And, автор скорее сам ищет пример кода. Вопрос сформулирован достаточно четко, и проблема не связана с ошибками в коде автора. Я проголосовал за вопрос, так считаю его полезным.

Comment: Готовый пример - http://jsfiddle.net/xqEV2/4/

Answer (score 3):

*Ввиду отсутствия вашего кода мог лишь показать пример:*

```css
#test {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.100);
  border: 20px solid #000;
}

/*Фон body*/
body {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id='test'>
  </div>
</body>
```